# `Rcmd.exe` does nothing

Tags: r, build

I am trying to build an R package on the command line in Windows.
I successfully got `devtools::create` to create a package template and created a file in the `R` directory with a simple function.
According to various guides, the next step is to use the `R CMD build` (or `Rcmd build`) command to build the package.
When I call that command from the terminal (have tried both Git Bash and Powershell) nothing happens.
There are no errors or messages, I just immediately get back control of the terminal.
Using `$?` I can see that the command did not execute successfully, but I get no information about why.
If I just run `R CMD` (or `Rcmd`) I get the help message, but almost all subcommand just do nothing.

What could the error be and how can I fix it?

---

I originally tried using `devtools::build()` in the R interactive prompt where I got

```
> devtools::build()
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
─────────────────────────
Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, …`:
! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
---
Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr: <printed>
---
Type .Last.error to see the more details.
```

I believe this stems from the same issue.

I have tried installing both the newest version (4.3.1) and previous version (4.2.3) of R and behaviour is the same.

I know that the terminal is finding the write executable as evidenced by the fact that I can get the help message, so the PATH is not the problem.